# Xamarin Android Accessibility Service Leaks Memory

Tags: .net, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

Running an accessibility service that traverses `AccessibilityNodeInfo` from the `RootInActiveWindow` causes memory leaks. I've tested this on Android 6.x and 7.x on physical devices and in the emulator.

The easiest way to see this issue is to turn on the accessibility service and visiting a webpage that keeps triggering the `WindowContentChanged` event (for example, go to https://time.is).

Watching the app in the profiler you can see the accessibility service climb in memory forever. More specifically coming from the `GetWindowNodes` method in the example below.

- Am I doing something wrong here or this a bug in Xamarin Android?
- Is there any way for me to get around this?

## Example

#### MetaData Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged|typeWindowContentChanged"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagReportViewIds"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"/>
```

#### Service

```
[Service(Permission = "android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE", Label = "memtest")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" })]
[MetaData("android.accessibilityservice", Resource = "@xml/accessibilityservice")]
public class AccService : AccessibilityService
{
    private const string SystemUiPackage = "com.android.systemui";

    public override void OnAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e)
    {
        var root = RootInActiveWindow;
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.PackageName) || e.PackageName == SystemUiPackage ||
            root?.PackageName != e.PackageName)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (e.EventType)
        {
            case EventTypes.WindowContentChanged:
            case EventTypes.WindowStateChanged:
                var nodes = GetWindowNodes(root, e, null);
                break;
        }
    }

    public override void OnInterrupt()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a flat list of all nodes in this window.
    /// </summary>
    private List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> GetWindowNodes(AccessibilityNodeInfo n,
                                                       AccessibilityEvent e,
                                                       List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodes)
    {
        if (nodes == null)
        {
            nodes = new List<AccessibilityNodeInfo>();
        }

        if (n != null)
        {
            if (n.WindowId == e.WindowId && !(n.ViewIdResourceName?.StartsWith(SystemUiPackage) ?? false))
            {
                nodes.Add(n);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < n.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                GetWindowNodes(n.GetChild(i), e, nodes);
            }
        }

        return nodes;
    }
}
```

## Profiler results

The highlighted areas are **always** increasing with every call to the `OnAccessibilityEvent`:

[image: profiler results 1]
[image: profiler results 2]
[image: profiler results 3]
[image: profiler results 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing anything wrong? Bug? Nope...

Perform a Snapshot, refresh your browser page, perform another Snapshot, raise and repeat. You should not see any mem leaks. (at least I do not w/ your code on Xamarin.Android v7.1.0.35.

Those minor allocations will not be collected until the GC runs at least a minor collections, you could always place a `GC.Collect(0);` at the end of your `OnAccessibilityEvent` to immediately clean up your `List<AccessibilityNodeInfo>` allocations but the GC will run at some point in the future when it needs memory for additional allocations...

> In the absence of an explicit collection via GC.Collect() collections are on demand, based upon heap allocations. This is not a reference counting system; objects will not be collected as soon as there are no outstanding references, or when a scope has exited. **The GC will run when the minor heap has run out of memory for new allocations. If there are no allocations, it will not run.**

re: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/

#### Update:

I been running this **modified code** in a release build (`Xamirin.Android 7.1.0.35`) with the browser open on `tweeting.net` and filtering logcat.

With 20,000 calls and counting to the `OnAccessibilityEvent` method I am not seeing any memory issues yet...

Try it and compare the results...

```
public class AccService : AccessibilityService
{
    const string SystemUiPackage = "com.android.systemui";
    const string TAG = "MEMTEST";
    long originalMemory;
    long lastMemory;
    long currentMemory;
    long stabilizedMemory;
    long nodeCount;
    long stabilizeCount;
    long cycleCount;

    public AccService(IntPtr javaReference, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        originalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
    }

    public AccService()
    {
        originalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
    }

    public override void OnAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e)
    {
        var root = RootInActiveWindow;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.PackageName) || e.PackageName == SystemUiPackage ||
            root?.PackageName != e.PackageName)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (e.EventType)
        {
            case EventTypes.WindowContentChanged:
            case EventTypes.WindowStateChanged:
                var nodes = GetWindowNodes(root, e, null);

                nodeCount = nodes.Count;
                foreach (var item in nodes)
                {
                    item.Dispose();
                }
                nodes = null;
                currentMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
                if (stabilizeCount < 20)
                {
                    stabilizeCount++;
                    stabilizedMemory = currentMemory;
                }
                cycleCount++;
                Log.Info(TAG, $"{(currentMemory == lastMemory ? "Stable " : (currentMemory > lastMemory ? "Growing" : "Shrink "))} / C{currentMemory} vs. S{stabilizedMemory} / Change: {currentMemory - lastMemory} / {lastMemory - stabilizedMemory}  / {cycleCount}:{nodeCount}");
                if (currentMemory > stabilizedMemory * 2)
                    Log.Error(TAG, $"Runaway memory : {currentMemory} vs. {stabilizedMemory}");
                lastMemory = currentMemory;

                break;
        }
    }
    ~~~
}
```

#### Logcat:

```
Info (5080) / MEMTEST: Stable  / C4316936 vs. S4316888 / Change: 0 / 48  / 21015:6
```

Comment: You are right about the snapshot and refresh. I do see some GC happening when I do that, however, it never seems to recover all the way. Every GC results in a memory state that is higher than the last GC. I have tried calling `GC.Collect(0)` after each event as you suggested but it doesn't seem to make any difference event by event. If I leave the window open for several hours on that website (even with refreshes and doing other things on the device) the memory just climbs forever (observed several hundred MB) and it eventually crashes the app.

Comment: If you care, you can see the real app implementation here as well: https://github.com/bitwarden/mobile/blob/master/src/Android/AutofillService.cs

Comment: @kspearrin Cool app, i'll try to find some time to check it out later...  When you are stating the memory just keeps increases, is that with just your `GetWindowNodes` code shown in your question, or in the actual app doing something more with results from `GetWindowNodes`?

Comment: It's just the `GetWindowNodes` method which includes the same things highlighted in the profiler screenshots from the test project. I'm seeing the same thing happen in both the test code in this post and in the real app implementation. I just wanted to isolate the problem so other factors could be ruled out (as you are pointing out now).

Comment: You can find the test code setup in an isolated project attached to this bug report on Xamarin's bugzilla: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52616 (though you may have already set up your own based on your original answer).

Comment: @kspearrin Xamarin is not without its faults involving mem leaks, you can track the PRs to see that, but *most* of the time is the user's code... ;-) Which version of `Xamarin.Android` are you using (did not see it in your bugzilla report)? Also I do not get `WindowContentChanged` events after the initial page (and iframe/ad) loads on sites like `time.is` (the JS is running and updating the time) using browser like Chrome Dev, manually refreshes works fine, but letting the browser self-refresh a DOM element is not firing `WindowContentChanged`, are you doing something else to get it to fire?

Comment: My real app is running the latest `Xamarin.Forms` `2.3.3.180` with `Xamarin.Android` `23.3.0` (see here https://github.com/bitwarden/mobile/blob/master/src/Android/packages.config). For the test app code in this post (one on bugzilla), I am not really sure how to see the `Xamarin.Android` version since it's not installed via nuget packages (just a standard Android app without Forms)? It should be whatever the latest is (I just created a new Android app in Xamarin Studio).

Comment: I'm not sure why you are not getting `WindowContentChanged` events from `time.is` in Chrome. I just tested again using the test app in an Android emulator using the default Android browser and I get a `WindowContentChanged` with every second tick on that website. Basically any window in the Android OS that changes should cause those events to keep firing (though you may need to remove the (`e.PackageName == SystemUiPackage` check at the beginning of `OnAccessibilityEvent`). `time.is` was just a handy site that I found that demonstrated the problem quickly without having to interact manually.

Comment: `23.3.0` is the Android support version, not a Xamarin version. In Xamarin Studio, open About box and select detail, should be something like `Xamarin.Android Version: 7.1.0.35 Enterprise`...

Comment: @kspearrin I am only getting `WindowContentChanged` events once a minute, on `time.is`, that is when the tab title is updated (tested with Firefox(Gecko) and Chrome Dev)... uhhhh, it is the SystemUiPackage check... that is want I get for cut/pasting code without reading it all...

Comment: `Xamarin.Android Version: 7.0.2.42 (Visual Studio Enterprise)`. I guess you'll have to find another window that can trigger it more rapidly. Try going to Settings > Developer Options > Running Services. That screen lists a bunch of apps with timers that update every second (also shows memory usage of the app there). You might need to remove the `SystemUIPackage` check I mentioned in the previous comment though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136117/discussion-between-kspearrin-and-sushihangover).

Comment: Wow I did not realize that the node was disposable! I'll give this a try soon and report back.

Comment: @kspearrin I pulled that out of some of the `Accessibility` work that I have done. I just killed the service code I listed and it was at 123k+ entries of `OnAccessibilityEvent` with over 800k nodes and not one leak in Mono or Java/ART, I had Android Monitor also running the entire time to monitor the process.... again that is using `7.1.0.35` so your results may vary....

Comment: @kspearrin I'm stickler for making sure any `IDisposable` is cleanup up, **especially** when dealing with objects that go across the Mono<->ART bridge... , that is except for `HttpClient`, which is one `IDisposable` that should always be treated as an app-level singleton....

Comment: Working great now! No more leaks. Thanks so much. Not sure if you want to update your answer anymore, but I will accept now.